# take a csv file as input from user using React and send it as a post request using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, csv, server

**this is my react code i get an empty result when i console.log(req.body) on my express server (like this-> { body: {} }) i should get all data inside that csv file in my server plz help, thank you in advance**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const Form = () => {
    const [csvFile, setCSVFile] = useState();

const sendRequst = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:4040/inventory/customer-segmentation', { body: csvFile });
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
};

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(csvFile)  (*i get this File {name: 'convertcsv.csv', lastModified: 1636535333170, lastModifiedDate: Wed Nov 10 2021 14:38:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 3491, …}*)
    sendRequst();
};


return (
    <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input
                type='file'
                accept='.csv'
                onChange({(e) => {
                    setCSVFile(e.target.files[0]);
            }}
            />
            <br />
            <button type='submit'>
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>
    </div>
);
};

export default Form;
```

Comment: There are few errors in your component. First, react sets state asynchronously, so `sendRequest` is called before actual state change. Then, your variable `csvFile` will not change when state will be changed. When state changes your component will be called and there will be completely new variable named `csvFile`.

Comment: @Mr.Hedgehog now i change my code little bit, now i get a csv file when console.log(csvFile) inside handleSubmit ( ) i get following in my browser console File {name: 'convertcsv.csv', lastModified: 1636535333170, lastModifiedDate: Wed Nov 10 2021 14:38:53 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 3491, …}

Comment: Now you need to send your file. You can do this in multiple ways. One would be as a field of [form data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects). Another would be reading file on client and sending this as binary data. Then, since your file is essentially text, you can read it on client and send it's content as text. I don't know what exactly you want and not sure how it is done with axios - I haven't worked with axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i have done a similar task today i like to post an answer to help the future readers :) (i also use typescript, tailwindcss(for styling) on the following answer which you can ignore it if you don't use neither of tools.

---

you can use FormData in order to send a csv file in a post request, i think this is the simplest way to send files in a post request.

in React you can create a simple form and put an input element with the **type="file"** inside. so that your can then use **useState** hook to save it as a state. after saving the file using useState hook you can simply use

```
formdata.append(name, value)
```

and then put the formdata inside the body of axios post request.
(as a good practice write onSubmit={handleSubmit} on  tag not on the submit button)

```
const [csvFile, setCsvFile] = useState <Blob>();

const formData = new FormData();

if (csvFile){
 formData.append('path_to_csv', csvFile);
}

const handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    if (e.currentTarget.files) setCsvFile(e.currentTarget.files[0]);
};

const handleSubmit = (e:React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
 e.preventDefault();

 async function fetchData() {
 const res:any = await axios.post(
   'http://127.0.0.1:8000/end_point_name_here/',
   formData,
   );
   console.log(res.data);
  }
  fetchData();
};

  return (
      <div className="flex flex-col gap-6 justify-center items-center h-screen">
        <h1> Page Title</h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input type="file" accept=".csv" onChange={handleChange} />
          <button type="submit" className="bg-blue-500 px-4 py-2 rounded-md font-semibold">fetch</button>
        </form>
      </div>
  );
};
```